# Missing ["connectionName"] in new TableObject [CakePHP 3.x]

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I created a new Table per Migration for my project to enable AutoLogin per Cookie. 
My problem is, that the TableObject is missing it's ["connectionName"] property on initialize.

I tried to find a way to fix this, but the only way I found was setting the Connection with the ConnectionManager. This will work for now, but I'd really like to know where I made a mistake, and why the connectionName isn't set to 'default' on its own.

My Migrationfile looks like this:

```
public function change()
{
  $table = $this->table('autologins', ['id' => false, 'primary_key' => 'id']);

  $table->addColumn('id', 'uuid', [
    'limit' => 36,
    'null' => false,
  ]);
  $table->addColumn('token', 'string',[
    'null' => false,
    'limit' => 32,
  ]);
  $table->addColumn('user_agent', 'string',[
    'null' => false,
    'limit' => MysqlAdapter::TEXT_TINY,
  ]);
  $table->addColumn('user_id', 'uuid',[
    'limit' => 36,
    'null' => false,
  ]);
  $table->addColumn('expiry_date', 'datetime',[
    'null' => false,
  ]);

  $table->create();
}
```

Without setting the Connection

```
$this->setConnection(ConnectionManager::get('default'));
```

I get the following var_dump:

```
object(App\Model\Table\AutologinsTable)#486 (8) { 
["registryAlias"]=> string(10) "Autologins" 
["table"]=> string(10) "autologins" 
["alias"]=> string(10) "Autologins" 
["entityClass"]=> string(26) "App\Model\Entity\Autologin" 
["associations"]=> array(0) { } 
["behaviors"]=> array(0) { } 
["defaultConnection"]=> string(7) "default" 
["connectionName"]=> NULL }
```